# How to hide/show all checkbox in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, view

I'm trying to do a listview like some android explorer, which if you make a long click on an item a checkbox appear in all rows.

I have the next Adapter, and the next code in my fragment, it do it, but for some reason, one row is not changing.

```
public class MultiListAdminTiemposAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MultiListAdminTiempos> {

    ArrayList<MultiListAdminTiempos> multiListAdminTiemposArrayList;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public MultiListAdminTiemposAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MultiListAdminTiempos> multiListAdminTiemposArrayList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, multiListAdminTiemposArrayList);
        this.multiListAdminTiemposArrayList = multiListAdminTiemposArrayList;
        this.mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public ArrayList<MultiListAdminTiempos> getSelectedList() {
        return this.multiListAdminTiemposArrayList;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_name, tv_tarea, tv_hours;
        private CheckBox chk_tiempo;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_admin_tiempos, null);

            holder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.tv_tarea = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tarea);
            holder.tv_hours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hours);
            holder.chk_tiempo = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo);

            holder.chk_tiempo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
                    MultiListAdminTiempos item = (MultiListAdminTiempos) checkBox.getTag();
                    item.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());

                    for(int i = 0; i < multiListAdminTiemposArrayList.size(); i++){
                        Log.e("CHK_T", "" + multiListAdminTiemposArrayList.get(i).getId() + "::" + multiListAdminTiemposArrayList.get(i).isSelected());
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MultiListAdminTiempos item = multiListAdminTiemposArrayList.get(position);

        holder.tv_name.setText(item.getProject_name());
        holder.tv_tarea.setText(item.getTask_name());
        holder.tv_hours.setText(parseTime(item.getHours()));

        holder.chk_tiempo.setChecked(item.isSelected());

        holder.chk_tiempo.setTag(item);

        return convertView;
    }

    public String parseTime(int min) {
        int hours = min / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
        int minutes = min % 60;

        String lb_hour = (hours == 1 ? mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.HORA_STRING) : mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.HORAS_STRING));
        String lb_minute = (minutes == 1 ? mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.MINUTO_STRING) : mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.MINUTOS_STRING));
        String time = "";

        time += hours + " " + lb_hour;
        if (minutes > 0) {
            time += "\n" + minutes + " " + lb_minute;
        }

        return time;
    }

}
```

My listview code:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_tiempos, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        list_admin_tiempos = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_admin_tiempos);
        list_admin_tiempos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (selecting) {

                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo);
                    changeCheckBoxState(chk);

                                /*
                                if (areAllUnchecked(parent)) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount(); i++) {
                                        parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                    selecting = false;
                                }*/

                }
                else {
                    //Vamos al detalle
                    viewDetail(position);
                }
            }
        });

        list_admin_tiempos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (!selecting) {

                    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
                    item.setVisible(true);

                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    //changeCheckBoxState( ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo)));

                    selecting = true;
                }else if (selecting) {

                    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
                    item.setVisible(false);

                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    //changeCheckBoxState( ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_tiempo)));

                    selecting = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Screenshot, when I scroll down the list:

[image]